# How can I deactivate a function code in ABAP?

Tags: abap

I know it is possible to inactivate functions codes in ABAP.
In my reports I can code it:

```
  DATA pf_exclude TYPE TABLE OF repid.
  APPEND 'MYFUNC' TO pf_exclude.   
  SET PF-STATUS 'LIST' EXCLUDING pf_exclude.
```

But there is also a way to do it in the GUI status, but how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the status maintenance (SE41) is a button to set the function to (in)active:

[image: Screenshot]

This button is only visible in change mode.